# Back button LEFT offset for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, button, uinavigationbar, back

I'm trying to move UINavigationBar back button right and I tried to do it with `UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left:20, bottom: -12, right: 0)` It moves up but doesn't move right at all. I did different combinations and read a lot of answers.
I hope someone knows how to move it and what is the best practice in this case. Should I make custom navigation bar? I don't want to make custom back button cause I need to assign it in every vc in stack.

Comment: you are dealing with bottom value of Uiedgeinsets change the right/left value according to your req

Comment: @Vinodh as you can see I set value for left inset too. If I understand what u mean)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with making custom back button)